# Shared property for clases in javascript ES-2015

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement base logic with classes in JavaScript using AngularJs. Here an example:

```
class Animal {
  constructor($scope, service) {
    'ngInject';
    let vm = this;
    vm.service = service;
    service.getAll().then((result) => {
        vm.animals = result;
    });
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor($scope, $log, service) {
    'ngInject';
    super($scope, service);
    let vm = this;
    vm.save = save;

    function save() {
      service.add(vm.newAnimal).then((result) => {
        vm.animals = result;
      });
  }
}
```

The problem is that changes from inherit class doesn't make sense for `super.animals` and that object won't be updated as a result my view doesn't rerender list with objects. What's wrong with my code or logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a problem with async operation. super.animals is not yet when you call Animal constructor with super.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Is it any easy way to fix it?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Right now I've solved it via `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess' ...)` but it looks like bad solution.

Comment: I don't know angularJS sorry. But I think one fix could be : vm.animals = service.getAll; and then wherever you need this method in the inherithed class you can call like this : vm.animals().then(...)

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo It could be work but the purpose of this property was to share it and forget about initialization in inherit classes :-)

Comment: In that case I can't figure out how to do it =( Hope someone could help you!

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo thank you anyway!

Comment: Who calls `save` and when? Why `vm.animals` assignment is necessary in super constructor if it will be overridden in child? It is not clear how the code is supposed to fit the app. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @estus why not? I have four controllers which need access to one collection from service. Some of them can modify it, another only read it.